# Using tkinter with ibPy

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am trying to use tkinter with ibPy.  I am using Spyder (Spyder 2.3.0).  When I enter the sample program

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I receive the message:

```
  File "/Users/Ameade/Tkinter.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tkinter import *

ImportError: No module named tkinter
```

Do you know where I can get this module?  I am working on a Mac (OSX 10.9.4).

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Some versions use lowercase `tkinter`, some use uppercase `Tkinter`. (And if you need the upper case version, you should probably change the name of your own file from `Tkinter.py` to something else.)

Comment: This is what Spyder says in About... 
Spyder 2.3.0 
The Scientific PYthon Development EnviRonment

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the version of python you are using.

`import tkinter` works on python 3(instead of Tkinter)

Comment: The formatting of your answer is strange. It looks like you were trying to post working code, but it is not correct syntax.

Comment: Thx.  I got this sample from http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-tkinter.htm

Answer (score 0):

It seems you named your sample program file `Tkinter.py`. You should change this name to something else and it should work.

**EDIT**
As [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953482/kevin) said, give to the file any other name but not the name of a python module (the extension must remain `.py`), so you could name it `my_amazing_program.py`. And keep the content of the file the same as you originally posted it - if you're using python 3+:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you're using python 2+ change `tkinter` to `Tkinter` on the import line:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you tell me what I should name it (including extension)?  Thx.

Comment: I changed the code to:

from Tkinter import *

root = tk()


w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")

w.pack()


root.mainloop()

Now the error is:  


  File "Tkinter.py", line 9, in <module>
    root = tk()

NameError: name 'tk' is not defined

Comment: _"Can you tell me what I should name it?"_ Anything ending in .py, not already taken by an existing module. I recommend `my_amazing_script.py`.

Comment: Thanks.  I did this and tried to Run.  This is what I got:


  File "/Users/Ameade/.spyder2/My_Amazing_Script.py", line 9, in <module>
    root = tk()

NameError: name 'tk' is not defined

p.s. how do you add carriage returns to these comments?  I tried Shift+Enter but no dice.

Comment: You can use [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) in comments too.

Comment: It means you're using Python 2+. You can see the version of python in the Spyder's `Internal console` or in it's `IPython console`.